# Как сделать один id (primary key) в mysql таблице непохожим на другие?

Tags: mysql

Для технических нужд требуется одну из записей в таблице сделать с id, выпадающим из общего ряда, но так, чтобы это не повлияло на последовательность auto_increment.

-1 не годится, так как поле unsigned

0 не годится, так как в приложении есть проверки на empty

999999 подошел бы, но как быть с auto_increment?

И в целом, какой подход обычно практикуется для решения такой задачи?

Comment: Отдельная колонка?

Comment: @D-side, цель не оправдывает такие средства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, конечно, стреляете себе в ногу, но если очень хочется, можно добавить нужную вам строку с большим id, а потом сбросить автоинкремент на старое значение:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` AUTO_INCREMENT = 42
```

> И в целом, какой подход обычно практикуется для решения такой задачи?

Вам нужно, чтобы она была всегда наверху/внизу какого-то списка? Сделайте это лучше дополнительным полем "сортировка" или, на худой конец, просто костылём в коде. То, что вы придумали, очень-очень плохо и когда-нибудь обязательно выйдет боком.

Comment: Это не приведет к неправильной работе первичного ключа, если максимальное значение его будет больше 42? А вообще вопрос как раз скорее о том, как добиться приемлемого результата и не отстрелить себе ногу. И какие практики применяются в подобных случаях.

Comment: Самый надёжный и простой способ не отстрелить себе ногу - не делать так. Что у вас за "технические нужды" такие?

Comment: Добавляю постоянную тестовую запись в таблицу с "живыми" записями. Данных там немного - содержимое почти статично (строка добавляется несколько раз в месяц, в будущем планируется 1-3 строки в год). Просьба руководства - присвоить какой-то "нерядовой" id.

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы она была всегда наверху/внизу какого-то списка? Сделайте это лучше дополнительным полем "сортировка" или, на худой конец, просто костылём в коде. То, что вы придумали, очень-очень плохо и когда-нибудь обязательно выйдет боком.

Comment: Увы, там дело не в сортировке - это было бы достаточно просто. Руководство хочет именно "чтобы id не был похож на другие". Ну как я понимаю, чтобы сразу было видно везде и всюду, что она необычная. Да, я подозревал, что это решение на практике может навредить. Попробую переубедить.